# MULTIPLE CONDITION COUNT IFS FORMULA IN EXCEL

Tags: excel

i have an excel table which contains index no. in a2:a34036, year in b2:b34036 and hourly data of 24 hours ranging from e2:ab34036. i want to count  no. of hourly vales that are >10 for each index and year. for this i have made another table in which vertically all index are placed and years are placed horizontally and i's using the formula

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A%34036,$B34040,$B$2:$B$34036,C$34039,$E$2:$AB$34036,">10")
```

but this formula does not return any value whether it is entered as direct or array formula. In place of $E$2:$AB$34036 if i use $E$2:$E$34036 i.e. for single column then it gives the result but doing this job for  24 times it is difficult. please help me

Comment: This may be of help http://www.howtogeek.com/194705/how-to-disable-or-reassign-the-caps-lock-key-on-any-operating-system/

Comment: can you provide some sample data/table?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new column after or before your hourly data, counting what you want for that row (assume new column in AC)

'

```
=COUNTIF(E2:AB2,">10")
```

and copy down

2. For the other table, use a sumifs instead of countifs

'

```
=SUMIFS(AC2:AC34036,$A$2:$A$34036,$B34040,$B$2:$B$34036,C$34039)
```

Though I would probably have placed this table in a separate sheet, to separate data and report.

Note also that your formula contains a % where it should be a $

Just out of curiosity, are all indices unique, or do they occur multiple times?